# Function failes when doing wmi queries in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am attempting to get remote registry values from a server using powershell.

I found some code online that worked for me:

```
$strComputer = "remoteComputerName"    
$reg = [mcrosoft.win32.registryKey]::openRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$strComputer)
$regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion")
$regKey.getValue("ProgramFilesDir")
```

but when I try to put it in a function:

```
$strComputer = "remoteComputerName"

function getRegValue {
    param($computerName, $strPath, $strKey)
    $reg = [mcrosoft.win32.registryKey]::openRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computerName) #Errors out here
    $regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($strPath)
    $regKey.getValue($strKey)
}

$a = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion"
$b = "ProgramFilesDir"
getRegValue($strComputer, $a, $b)
```

errors out:

```
Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The endpoint format is invalid."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the parens and the commas when you call the function.

Comment: I feel foolish... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call your function as follows as the current format is causing the issue.

```
getRegValue $strComputer $a $b
```

Comment: This answer is correct. To clarify: When you call a function in PowerShell, don't use parentheses or separate the parameters with commas.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this type of issue, you can use PowerShell's strictmode.
This option throws exceptions when encountering improper syntax (which is the case for your function call).

```
function someFunction{
param($a,$b,$c)
Write-host $a $b $c
}

> someFunction("param1","param2","param3")
> # Nothing happens

> Set-strictmode -version 2
> someFunction("param1","param2","param3")

The function or command was called as if it were a method. Parameters should
be separated by spaces. For information about parameters, see the
about_Parameters Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ someFunction("param1","param2","param3")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StrictModeFunctionCallWithParens
```